# How to convert date format for two datetime in bash?

Tags: bash, datetime, unix, sed

I have to convert the datetime from `"Apr 10 16 07:03:04"` format to `"\[10\/12\/16 07:03:04 BST]"` format. I am using the following function.

```
convert_date () {
local months=( Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec )
local i
for (( i=0; i<11; i++ )); do
    [[ $1 = ${months[$i]} ]] && [[ $5 = ${months[$i]} ]] && break
done
printf "\[%2d\/%02d\/%02d $4 BST]\n" $2 $(( i+1 )) $3
printf "\[%2d\/%02d\/%02d $8 BST]\n" $6 $(( i+1 )) $7    
}

d=$( convert_date $1 $2 $3 $4 )
e=$( convert_date $5 $6 $7 $8 )
echo $d
echo $e
```

Where my input will be

```
./date.sh Apr 10 16 07:03:04 May 12 16 08:11:09
```

and my output should be

```
\[10\/12\/16 07:03:04 BST]
\[12\/12\/16 08:11:09 BST]
```

But I am getting the following output like,

```
\[10\/12\/16 07:03:04 BST] \[12\/00\/00 BST]
\[12\/12\/16 08:11:09 BST] \[12\/00\/00 BST]
```

How to get the exact output? Please Help.

Comment: why don't you use `date` to do changes in the date format? Otherwise this is quite fragile

Comment: I cannot get the exact output with `date`. Also I use variable instead of using hardcore  value.

Comment: I doubt you cannot get this exact output with `date`. I've done some tests and it looks quite possible. Check for example `date -d"Apr 10 2016 07:03:04" "+[%d\/%m"`.

Comment: Sorry I cannot use `date`. Can you help me to identify why `\[12\/00\/00 BST]` comes in my output?

Comment: The escaped backslashes in your expected output lead me to think this is an XY problem. What are you actually *doing* with the result of `convert_date`?

Comment: Also, you are only passing 4 arguments to `convert_date`, but expecting at least 7.

Comment: I have to pass the result to a command that gives me the data between the two datetime

Answer (score 2):

I would write the function like this:

```
function convert_date() {

    # First sanitize input to something the date command can understand
    # The problem here is just the 16 which should be 2016
    input="$(awk -v year="$(date +%Y)" '{$3=year}1' <<< ${1})"

    # Now use the date command to reformat the string
    date -d"${input}" +'[%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S %Z]'
}
```

Call it like this:

```
convert_date 'Apr 10 16 07:03:04'
```

Output (if your local time is BST):

```
[10/04/16 07:03:04 BST]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your method looks quite unusual, I would probably have used `date` instead of a script. But if you remove the second `printf`, the output seems to match your expected format. I'm not sure why it was there in the first place.

Comment: I cannot use date because my input is in such a format that it should include a filename and two datetimes. However my first `printf` is used to display the result. And I can get my desired output when I remove my second `printf`. Thanks